# If the base and fiber of a fiber bundle are complex manifolds, is the total space a complex manifold?

Tags: fiber-bundles, complex-manifolds

Let $\pi: E\rightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle with fibers $F$. If $B$ and $F$ are complex manifolds, does this imply $E$ is also a complex manifold?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Initially, your question seemed to ask: if the total space and fibre were complex manifolds, is the base a complex manifold? The answer is no, one interesting example arises from twistor geometry. There is a fibre bundle

$$\mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^3 \to S^4$$

called the Penrose fibration. Although the fibre and the total space are complex manifolds, the base is not (it doesn't even admit an almost complex structure).

---

Your actual question was: if the fibre and the base are complex manifolds, is the total space a complex manifold? Again the answer is no.

The Klein bottle $K$ is a fibre bundle with $S^1$ fibre and $S^1$ base, so there is a fibre bundle

$$S^1\times S^1 \to K\times K \to S^1\times S^1.$$

Although $S^1\times S^1$ admits a complex structure, $K\times K$ does not (complex manifolds are orientable).

Comment: Nice, but I was wondering in this case e.g $S^3\times S^5\rightarrow \mathbb CP^1\times \mathbb CP^2$ (Hopf fibration)  where the fiber ( torus $S^1\times S^1$) and the base are complex manifolds then why this implies that $S^3\times S^5$ is also a complex manifold?

Comment: As you can see from my examples, it doesn't. If you are trying to understand why $S^3\times S^5$ admits a complex structure, I suggest you ask a new question and include a quote from the reference you are using.

Comment: I will thank you very much.

Comment: Very nice answer!  I have used the Penrose bundle before, but have never heard it called that (and I am only vaguely aware of twistor bundles).  For those who want to understand where the Penrose bundle comes from:  From identifying $\mathbb{C}^{2n}\cong \mathbb{H}^n$, we can complete any complex line in $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ to a complex line in $\mathbb{H}^n$ via $span\{v\}\rightarrow span\{v, jv\}$.  This gives a map $\mathbb{C}P^{2n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}P^{n-1}$ which turns out to be fiber bundle with fiber $S^2$.  When $n=2$, you get Michael's example, as $\mathbb{H}P^1\cong S^4$.