# $S^{2n+1}\times S^{2m+1}$ is a complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $\pi: S^{2n+1}\rightarrow \mathbb CP^n$ be the quotient map. Then $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1$ since $\pi(e^{i\theta}z)=\pi(z)$ for all $\theta$ where $z\in S^{2n+1}$.

Now let's consider the fibration $S^{2n+1}\times S^{2m+1}\rightarrow \mathbb CP^n\times \mathbb CP^m$ which has fiber the torus $S^1\times S^1$. How can we now conclude that $S^{2n+1}\times S^{2m+1}$ is a complex manifold?

Comment: You can't as my answer to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2183942/39599) shows. Is there a reference you're using that suggests that the existence of this fibration implies $S^{2n+1}\times S^{2m+1}$ is a complex manifold? Note, $S^{2n+1}\times S^{2m+1}$ does indeed admit a complex structure, but it isn't due to the existence of this fibration.

Comment: I dont know if you can open this link page 11 https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AAvtrugECd46OD8&cid=7ADF7E66D6C30E6A&id=7ADF7E66D6C30E6A%213088&parId=7ADF7E66D6C30E6A%213014&o=OneUp

Comment: From the link it seems to say that $\mathbb S^{2n+1} \times \mathbb S^{2m+1}$ can be given a complex structure so that $\pi$ is holomorphic. And it is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't exactly know what the author meant by the paragraph you're referring to as the total space of a fiber bundle with fiber and base a complex manifold need not be a complex manifold; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2183942/39599).

The manifolds $S^{2n+1}\times S^{2m+1}$ do admit a complex structure which can be obtained as a quotient of $(\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times(\mathbb{C}^{m+1}\setminus\{0\})$ by the $\mathbb{C}$-action $t\cdot(x, y) = (e^tx, e^{\alpha t}y)$ where $\alpha$ is a complex number with $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha) \neq 0$. They are called [Calabi-Eckmann manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Eckmann_manifold).

Comment: Thank you. But why is this condition $Im(\alpha)\not = 0$?